# Automapper Map one class to two

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 app using Automapper 12.0.0 and I defined a mapper profile where I map one class to two different ones:

```
public class ModelMapper : AutoMapper.Profile
{
   public ModelMapper()
   {
      CreateMap<A, B1>().ReverseMap();
      CreateMap<A, B2>().ReverseMap();
   }
}
```

And then:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ModelMapper));
```

When I try to map from B2 to A I get this error:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: B2 -> A

Is there a way to set up AutoMapper to be able to map from A to B1 and to B2 and also from B1 to A and from B2 to A ?

Comment: I think you need to add these lines in Configure method. CreateMap<A, B1>().ReverseMap();
      CreateMap<A, B2>().ReverseMap();

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

B1 had a property of class C1
B2 had a property of class C2
A had a property of class D

I forgot to map C1->D and C2->D

The error is misleading because it mentions B1, but the real issue was **inside** B1.

Comment: If you look at `exception.ToString()`, I'm sure you'll find everything. So no, the exception is not misleading, you just didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was always me, but adding profiles this way never worked for me.

So I was always adding them this way:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMapper>(factory =>
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(x => x.AddProfiles(new Profile[]
        {
            new ModelMapper()
        }));

        return new Mapper(config);
    });

    return serviceCollection;
}
```

Also make sure that class A and B are matching with names, etc. If not then you would have to remove reverse map and add `MapFrom`

Comment: Unfortunatelly that didn't work for me, the result is exactly the same as using the initialization helper method. What do you mean with "make sure that class A and B are matching with names, etc."? Class names don't need to match. Property names do match.